# Android - Uploading an existing (internal memory) file on google drive

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I spent the last 8 hours to find a way to upload a file from the internal memory of my android phone to a google drive account.
I'm very frustrated right now. The official examples hosted at GitHub, explain how to take a photo and upload it on the drive. My problem is different, I already have a file on my device and I'd like to upload it on the drive.
Here is my last try (this is inspired by various examples found on the web):

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

```
private GoogleAccountCredential credential;
private static Drive service;
int ACCOUNT_REQUEST = 1;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(this, DriveScopes.DRIVE);
    startActivityForResult(credential.newChooseAccountIntent(), ACCOUNT_REQUEST);

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getExtras() != null) {
        String accountName = data.getStringExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME);
        if (accountName != null) {
            credential.setSelectedAccountName(accountName);
            Drive.Builder builder = new Drive.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(), new GsonFactory(), credential);
            builder.setApplicationName("Test Application");
            service =builder.build();
            uploadTheFile();
        }
    }


}

public void uploadTheFile() {
    String filePath = "storage/sdcard0/file.txt";
    String fileName = "File";
    File body = new File();
    body.setTitle(fileName);
    body.setDescription(fileName);
    body.setMimeType("text/plain");

    java.io.File fileContent = new java.io.File(filePath);
    FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent("text/plain", fileContent);

    try {
        File file = service.files().insert(body, mediaContent).execute();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I can select the account where to upload the file (file.txt), but then it crash with:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: calling this from your main thread can lead to deadlock

I've tried to give as many info as I can, if you need further info, don't exitate to ask! Thanks !

EDIT: Thanks to greenapps the deadlock problem is fixed, but I still can't upload my file: where should I put my client id and client secret ?? Thanks !

Comment: Your problem statement is incorrect as your source file is on what is considered the EXTERNAL STORAGE (even though perhaps permanently a part of the phone in your case) and not the internal, or app-private storage.  Also, you should not hard-code the file path as it will be different on difference devices and versions.

Comment: I know that i shouldn't hardcode the path, but this is just for a test..

Answer (score 1):

```
   String filePath = "storage/sdcard0/file.txt";
```

change that to

```
   String filePath = "/storage/sdcard0/file.txt";
```

And before uploading check if that file exists.

```
   File file = new File (filePath);

   if ( ! file.exists ) )
       {
        message that file does not exist

        return false;
       }
```

Your IllegalStateException can be solved by putting uploadFile() in an AsyncTask

Answer (score 0):

If you can get the photo upload "quick starter" demonstration code working (no small task in itself), try modifying that code to copy your file (instead of the photo) to Drive's outputStream as shown in the following code which worked for me. (I'm not a serious Java programmer so I wouldn't be surprised if there's a better way to copy a file to an outputStream.)

```
        public void onResult(ContentsResult result) {
            // Get an output stream for the contents.
            OutputStream outputStream = result.getContents().getOutputStream();

            // Write specified local file to Google Drive output stream.
            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            int nbyteWritten = 0;
            int nbyte;
            try {
                DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
                DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(outputStream);
                while ((nbyte = dis.read(buf)) > 0) {
                    dos.write(buf, 0, nbyte);
                    nbyteWritten += nbyte;
                }
                dis.close();
                dos.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Unable to write file contents.");
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should to a lot easier using the Android-specific API.  See [create files](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/create-file).  It handles all the authorization and uploading for you. Just copy the contents from your local file on disk into the OutputStream provided by the new contents object.